# iPhone X 'Short' Press failure

Tags: iphone, display

I observed an iPhone X that would not respond to the 'short' press: applications (including settings) would not open.  "long press" of the applications worked as expected.  I do not have the right keywords to search for this problem: I would like to know the root cause and any remedy.

The touchscreen display is not faulty: a hardware reset of the device resolved the issue.  Apple store checked the log and indicated there was no kernel panic.

- What are the keywords to identify the problem for a Google search?
- Is the root cause of said issue known and is there a fix?

Comment: Please help us understand what do you mean by short press? Do you mean tap? Please include a short video if that helps.

Comment: Yes, a quick tap vs. holding down the button for two seconds.